# Relational queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Just started out with MongoDB. I have collections called users, dishes, restaurants and ratings. I need to map the ratings to a particular dish and user.

```
Users
{
 _id: "12323421",
 name: "John Doe",
 ...
}

Dishes
{
 _id: "9872983749",
 name: "Apple Pie",
 restaurantID: "3432452" //Corresponds to Patisserie
 ...
}

Restaurants
{
 _id: "3432452",
 name: "Patisserie",
 ...
}

Ratings
{
 _id: "74766575",
 userID: "12323421", //Corresponds to John Doe
 dishID: "9872983749", //Corresponds to Apple Pie
 rating: 5
}
```

I dont know how to go about generating a few queries like:

- List of dishes with at least 10 ratings, or
- Restaurant whose dishes
  have received 10 ratings

This is pretty simple to implement in an SQL environment, but how does one use Joins, or nested queries in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not natively support joins or subqueries.

I would suggest that you take a step back and do some reading on MongoDB schema design. The [Data Modeling Concepts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-models/) section of the MongoDB docs is a great place to start. There are many other resources out there on the topic. The O'Reilly book ***MongoDB Applied Design Patterns*** is also a great resource.

If you head down the path of modeling your data in MongoDB in a similar manner to how you would model it in an RDBMS, you are setting yourself up for failure.

There is not always a clear "right" or "best" way to model a particular problem. It will always depend on the specific access patterns and requirements for your application.

As you mentioned in a comment, one approach would be to embed the ratings for a particular dish into the Dish collection. But this is problematic if you have a large number of ratings (unbounded growth is bad). A common approach here is often a hybrid. For example, you could embed the most popular or the most recent ratings for a particular dish and store other ratings in a separate collection. Again, think about how your application is going to present the data and try to model your data accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that modeling with MongoDB violates the concepts drilled into us while learning RDBMS, and this has proved to be quite disorienting, as well as liberating.

Comment: In the case of the above 'schema', I could easily have embedded the ratings within the dish collection itself, but that causes a problem for when a large number of ratings may be present.

Comment: Okay, so the approach while creating a model is kind of top-down (how the application will use the data) instead of bottom-up (representing the data in the most normalised way possible)...